# CloudFront redirection with ssl gives "invalid certificate" error when accessing https://company.com, but why?

Tags: ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I've configured an AWS CloudFront redirection (with SSL) using [this guide].[1](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-https-amazon-cloudfront/#installing-the-ssl-certificate)

I've configured an A record with Alias which points company.com. to the CloudFront domain name.

When I access the CloudFront domain name, the site is loaded successfully and appears secured.

But when I access the site by `https://company.com` I get a certificate error which says that the certificate is not valid.

The certificate I purchased is for `*.company.com`.

In chrome, I get the following error:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from angelsense.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). 
Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Automatically send some system information and page content to Google to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate is only valid for `*.angelsense.com`. It is not valid for `angelsense.com`. To use it without any subdomain you have to add `angelsense.com` additionally to `*.angelsense.com` as a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) when you create the certificate.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've issued a new certificate and now it works.